# Properties of a relation

Tags: relations

$\cong\;=\{((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2))\in \mathbb R^2 ×\mathbb R^2 |x_1^2-x_2^2=3y_1^2-3y_2^2\}$ finitary relation meaning $(x_1,y_1) \cong (x_2,y_2)$ if $x_1^2-x_2^2=3y_1^2-3y_2^2$
Is this finitary relation reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive?
Is it linear order? Is it equivalence?

Reflexivity: yes (?) since for example (2,2), (2,2): $2^2-2^2=3*2^2-3*2^2$
Symmetry: no (?) since for example (2,5), (5,2): $2^2-5^2\neq3*5^2-3*2^2$
Did I get it correctly? I'm not sure if I got the definitions of reflexivity, symmetry, etc. right...

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why this had to be marked as off-topic, I would appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me.
I created this question, because I need someone to provide me with a start on how to approach this question, as I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing reflexivity and symmetry in the relation with those properties within each ordered pair. For example, if you want to find a counter-example for the symmetry property, you need to show $((a,b),\;(c,d)) \in\; \cong $ but $((c,d),\;(a,b)) \not\in\; \cong$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Also, if you want to prove a property is true, such as for reflexivity, you can't show it's true just for a particular example. You have to show it's true for all values.

**Reflexive?** Yes. For all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\; x^2 - x^2 = 0 = 3y^2 - 3y^2 \quad$ so $((x,y),\;(x,y)) \in \;\cong$.

**Symmetric?** Yes. If $((x_1, y_1),\; (x_2,y_2)) \in \;\cong\;$ then
$$x_2^2 - x_1^2 = -(x_1^2 - x_2^2) = -(3y_1^2 - 3y_2^2) = 3y_2^2 - 3y_1^2.$$

So $((x_2, y_2),\; (x_1,y_1)) \in \;\cong$.

**Antisymmetric?** No. Counter-example:

$((0,1),\;(0,-1))$ and $((0,-1),\;(0,1))$ are in $\cong $ but $(0,1) \neq (0,-1)$.

**Transitive?** Yes. Suppose $((x_1, y_1),\; (x_2,y_2)) \in \;\cong \;$ and $((x_2, y_2),\; (x_3,y_3)) \in \;\cong$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1^2 - x_3^2 &=& (x_1^2 - x_2^2) + (x_2^2 - x_3^2) \\
&=& (3y_1^2 - 3y_2^2) + (3y_2^2 - 3y_3^2) \\
&=& 3y_1^2 - 3y_3^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

So $((x_1, y_1),\; (x_3,y_3)) \in \;\cong$.

**A Linear Order?** No, because $\cong\;$ is not antisymmetric.

**An Equivalence Relation?** Yes, because $\cong\;$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.